# ActiveMQ Exception Connection and domain type do not match

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, mule

Hi I am getting the below exception stack trace in my application logs.

20/09/2013 22.26.49    - Caught exception in Exception Strategy: Connection and domain type do not match
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Connection and domain type do not match
    at org.mule.transport.jms.Jms102bSupport.createSession(Jms102bSupport.java:108)
    at org.mule.transport.jms.JmsConnector.getSession(JmsConnector.java:579)
    at org.mule.transport.jms.JmsConnector.getSession(JmsConnector.java:558)
    at org.mule.transport.jms.JmsMessageDispatcher.dispatchMessage(JmsMessageDispatcher.java:141)
    at org.mule.transport.jms.JmsMessageDispatcher.doDispatch(JmsMessageDispatcher.java:73)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageDispatcher$Worker.run(AbstractMessageDispatcher.java:262)
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:310)
    at edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$CallerRunsPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1895)
    at edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:765)
    at edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1288)
    at org.mule.work.ScheduleWorkExecutor.doExecute(ScheduleWorkExecutor.java:41)

I cannot quite understand what it actually means,

can someone please explain what *Connection and domain type do not match means*

and probably a example scenario where it might occur.

Data is sent out using a mule outbound configured

```
<multicasting-router>

    <jms:outbound-endpoint topic="SAMPLEMESSAGES" transformer-refs="DomToXml ObjectToJms" connector-ref="jmsConnector" />

</multicasting-router>
```

Connector configuration can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/sudarshan89/6651572) cannot paste the xml here for some reason

Like archer mentioned i did look at the activeMQ source code, just pasting it here

```
@Override
    public Session createSession(Connection connection, boolean topic, boolean transacted,
        int ackMode, boolean noLocal) throws JMSException
    {
        if (connection == null)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Connection is null");
        }
        if (topic && connection instanceof TopicConnection)
        {
            return ((TopicConnection) connection).createTopicSession(noLocal, ackMode);
        }
        else if (connection instanceof QueueConnection)
        {
            // for transacted sessions the ackMode is always ignored, but
            // set it for readability (SESSION_TRANSACTION is recommented
            // for this case).
            return ((QueueConnection) connection).createQueueSession(
                    transacted, (transacted ? Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED : ackMode));
        }
        else
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Connection and domain type do not match, connection is of type " + connection.getClass().getName());
        }
    }
```

I want to understand under what circumstances can a incoming client connect not be a topicConnection or queueConnection , what client code can i write to cause the exception to occur

Thanks

Comment: Can you share your connector configuration?

Comment: By connector configuration, I meant the configuration of your jms connector (called jmsConnector)

Comment: I have added the connector configuration as a gist https://gist.github.com/sudarshan89/6651572 , I some how could not add it into the question

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify the JMS version to use in your ActiveMQ connector so Mule, by default, uses the old and deprecated version 1.0.2b of the spec.

Configure your connector to use 1.1 and see if you still have the issue. Also, if you specify a broker URL, you do not need to provide a connection factory.

So try with:

```
<jms:activemq-connector name="jmsConnector" specification="1.1"
                        brokerURL="tcp://10.209.130.10:61616">
    <spring:property name="retryPolicyTemplate" ref="ThreadingPolicyTemplate" />
</jms:activemq-connector>
```

Comment: Thanks I will give this a shot, however any thoughts on the possible scenarios under which this exception could be thrown, what must the client code do for this exception to occur ?

Comment: Hard to tell... Do you have an inbound JMS queue upstream of this outbound?

Comment: No, it gets data via a tcp inbound.

Comment: I am trying to figure out a way to reproduce this in a test environment but unable to do so, this occurred in our production set up. So any hints at the possible causes or anyway to code up a client which can result in this exception being thrown will be very helpful, to begin with i cannot understand what the exception message is trying to say :)

Comment: Maybe it's just trying to say that the JMS connector is badly configured and will behave erratically until the issue is fixed?

Answer (score 0):

You connection should be of type TopicConnection or QueueConnection. Otherwise this exception will be thrown. More details you can find reading the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mule.transports/mule-transport-jms/3.4.0/org/mule/transport/jms/Jms102bSupport.java#Jms102bSupport). Line 117.

Comment: Yes i did check the source code, however i could not understand under what conditions, that a connection might not be either of the two ?, can you give me an example or a way to reproduce the same

Comment: Actually we have defined the broker as above and expect clients to connect on the ip and port, so i am not sure about which code you would want to see

Comment: how do you send messages?

Comment: Data is sent out using a mule outbound endpoint, I have updated the question with the configuration

Comment: what happens if you replace topic="SAMPLEMESSAGES" to queue="SAMPLEMESSAGES"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37783/discussion-between-sudarshan-and-archer)